# Is it better to use a tricolon or an enumeration with four objects?

Tags: essay, conventions

I am not 100% sure if this is the correct SE to ask this question and if it is not I hope someone could be so kind to tell me where I should ask this question.

I am writing an essay (for school) and I was wondering whether I should sum up four facts that support my opinion or three instead.

On the one hand it seems logical that summing up one more fact would have a better effect, however, on the other hand, the presence of a separate name for summing up three items - tricolon - makes it seem as if a tricolon might actually be better than an enumeration summing just four facts.

So my question is, should I use a tricolon or an enumeration with four facts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of your 4 points are symmetrical in structure, 4 is fine.  4 sentences is a tetracolon.  If all of the facts are not similar in grammatical structure then nether 3 nor 4 is not an isocolon at all.